# manual sorting using PHP MySQL (Up/Down buttons)?

Tags: php, mysql

i m trying to do a manual ordering (sorting) of items in my table
not quite good at it and can't seem to figure it out so would like some help.
basically there's a column called 'sort' that stores integers,

```
    pid       |    pid       |   sort
    ----------+--------------+-------
    Alvin     |     1001     |    1
    Tom       |     1002     |    2
    Jerry     |     1003     |    3
```

i need help with the codes to repositioning the rows... i.e. I m using php to parse variables via URL sort.php?do=up&pid=1002&sort=2

Clicking "UP" on top would result in Tom becoming 1, and Alvin drops to 2

Then the desired outcome would be the sorting will now change to

```
    pid       |    pid       |   sort
    ----------+--------------+-------
    Alvin     |     1001     |    2
    Tom       |     1002     |    1
    Jerry     |     1003     |    3
```

Would also like to know the opposite of this which is a "DOWN" reorder

Much appreciated!

Comment: Use `ORDER BY column ASC` or `ORDER BY column DESC` that will give you an UP-DOWN sorting order. Then just use the query inside a function using an `isset` conditional statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but you'll catch my drift:

```
$pid = (int) $_GET['pid'];
$sort = (int) $_GET['sort'];

$update_pid = false;
if ($_GET['do'] == 'UP') {
    $update_pid = '-';
    $update_other = '+';
    $sort_other = $sort - 1;
} elseif ($_GET['do'] == 'DOWN') {
    $update_pid = '+';
    $update_other = '-';
    $sort_other = $sort + 1;
}

if ($update_pid) {
    $query_one = "
        UPDATE table 
        SET sort = sort " . $update_other ." 1 
        WHERE sort = " . $sort_other;
    $query_two = "
        UPDATE table 
        SET sort = sort " . $update_pid ." 1 
        WHERE pid = " . $pid;
}
```

If the order should be the other way round you can change the if-statements accordingly.

Comment: thanks! yup I think I can figure this out from this!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using jQuery Sortable for this: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Sorting elements on server side can be a nightmare, especially if you have many elements and want to move one from the top to the bottom or from the bottom to the top.

Comment: Thanks, have seen this option, but would like to know the good old method via SQL coding if possible

Comment: It's actually the BAD old method :) Plus, using jQuery Sortable you will need to update database as well. It would be just more user friendly, as the ordering process would be performed on client side and only one request would be processed on saving.